# Replacing Process builder with an Apex Trigger. Should the process builder be inactive during trigger deployment?

Tags: trigger, process-builder

We have an active Process builder which runs in Afterinsert context on CPQ Quote creation. Due to certain inefficiency and enhancements, we have replaced it with Apex Trigger.

However, during Trigger deployment, we are running into issue, as deployment is failing. I reckon it could be due to Process builder being active and running the updated for test data insertion.

Question: So is it best to deactivate process builder for the deployment?

Comment: Yes. Deactivate then deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform mentioned changes, it is wise to take as step back and check what kind of processes are happening at the environment. In case if your org is heavily used, process builder deactivation would stop part of the processes to be executed.

That can be critical in certain scenarios.

One of the approaches could be including a *Feature Switch* in trigger – a centralized way to turn on or of certain feature (which is based on custom settings or something else). 
I will require a bit of extra development (basically technical debt), but in that case activation of the new functionality could be less stressful, for example in case if there are errors in refactored logic or new functionality, then newly  (or recently) deployed feature can be deactivated.
In this particular case, you may deploy an inactive trigger, and then disable process builder and activate trigger in much shorter time, rather then deactivation of process builder and deployment of new metadata.

Another way you have already mentioned – disable process builder upfront, and perform deployment (preferably not during peak hours).

Here is a nice [article](https://www.ariasolutions.com/blog/salesforce-data-loads-feature-switches-manage-apex-triggers/) about feature switches.